# How do I need to change my sql to get what I want in this case?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by

I have a table like following:

```
id  value    date
1    5    2015-01-10
2    5    2015-06-13
3    5    2015-09-05
4    11   2015-02-11
5    11   2015-01-10
6    11   2015-01-25
```

As can be seen, every `value` appears 3 times with different `date`. I want to write a query that returns the unique `value`s that has the maximum `date`, which would be the following for the above table:

```
id  value    date
3    5    2015-09-05
4    11   2015-02-11
```

How could I do it?

## This is the updated question:

The real question I am encountering is a little bit more complicated than the simplified version above. I thought I can move a step further once I know the answer to the simplified version, but I guest I was wrong. So, I am updating the question herein.

I have 2 tables like following:

```
      Table 1
id  id2    date
1    2   2015-01-10
2    5   2015-06-13
3    9   2015-09-05
4    10  2015-02-11
5    26  2015-01-10
6    65  2015-01-25

      Table 2
id  id2    data
1    2       A
2    5       A
3    9       A
4    10      B
5    26      B
6    65      B
```

Here, `Table 1` and `Table 2` are joined by `id2`

What I want to get is two records as follows:

```
id2  date       data
9   2015-01-10    A
10  2015-02-11    B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to select the rows with the greatest date per value

```
select * from (
    select t2.id2, t1.date, t2.data, 
        row_number() over (partition by t2.data order by t1.date desc) rn
    from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id2
) t where rn = 1
```

Comment: This is the straight-forward way to do it. Mark the best record per value with row number 1 and only show those records then.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried to follow your idea but wasn't able to get anywhere as the real problem I am facing is a little bit more complicated that what I posted originally. I have updated the question just now. Thank you again.

Comment: @FuzzyTree Thank you again for the update. I still have problem getting what I need as I am actually joining 5 tables. I will take a further look and let you know if I still cannot figure it out.

Comment: @FuzzyTree The problem I am having is that I added the extra column in Table 1 by mistake. There is actually no `value` column in my table. So I was not able to do a parition by t1.value. I have updated the question again. Sorry for changing the question over and over again.

Comment: @Dainy partition by `t2.data` then

Comment: @FuzzyTree Are you saying that I only need to change `t1.value` into `t2.data`? Also, I am not sure what your t1 and t2 correspond to as you wrote `from mytable t1 join mytable t2` which seems that t1 and t2 are alias for the same table. By `t1.id = t2.id2`, you actually mean `t1.id2 = t2.id2`, correct? And I don't see you use `t` anywhere even though you have it on the last line.

Comment: @Dainy yes change t1.value to t2.data. t1 and t2 should be different tables. the unused t alias is required

Comment: Hi @FuzzyTree, I have a follow-up question on this and wondering if you could take a look and see if you could help me with that. Here is the link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502064/how-to-parse-varchar2-and-make-it-into-multiple-rows

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.id, a.value, a.date
from mytable a,
   ( select id, max(date) maxdate
       from mytable b
     group by id) b
where a.id = b.id
  and a.date = b.maxdate;
```

Comment: The idea is okay, but the comma-separated join syntax was out-dated more than 20 years ago with Standard SQL-92. (Admittedly, it took Oracle some years, but finally they adopted explicit ANSI joins with Oracle 9i in 2001).

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 ( id, id2, "date" ) AS
SELECT 1,    2,   DATE '2015-01-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    5,   DATE '2015-06-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,    9,   DATE '2015-09-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,    10,  DATE '2015-02-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,    26,  DATE '2015-01-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,    65,  DATE '2015-01-25' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table2 ( id, id2, data ) AS
SELECT 1,    2,       'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    5,       'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,    9,       'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,    10,      'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,    26,      'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,    65,      'B' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT MAX( t1.id  ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY t1."date" ) AS id,
       MAX( t1.id2 ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY t1."date" ) AS id2,
       MAX( t1."date" ) AS "date",
       t2.data
FROM   Table1 t1
       INNER JOIN
       Table2 t2
       ON ( t1.id = t2.id AND t1.id2 = t2.id2 )
GROUP BY t2.data
```

**Output**:

```
        ID        ID2 date                DATA
---------- ---------- ------------------- ----
         3          9 2015-09-05 00:00:00 A    
         4         10 2015-02-11 00:00:00 B
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT id,
       id2,
       "date",
       data
FROM   (
  SELECT t1.*,
         t2.data,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t2.data ORDER BY t1."date" DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   Table1 t1
         INNER JOIN
         Table2 t2
         ON ( t1.id = t2.id AND t1.id2 = t2.id2 )
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID        ID2 date                DATA
---------- ---------- ------------------- ----
         3          9 2015-09-05 00:00:00 A    
         4         10 2015-02-11 00:00:00 B
```

Comment: Thank you @MT0! I have already worked it out by following Fuzzy's method :-)

Comment: Hi @MT0, I have a follow-up question on this and wondering if you could take a look and see if you could help me with that. Here is the link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502064/how-to-parse-varchar2-and-make-it-into-multiple-rows