# How to parse varchar2 and make it into multiple rows?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

This is kind of a follow-up question of this one: [How do I need to change my sql to get what I want in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36487663/how-do-i-need-to-change-my-sql-to-get-what-i-want-in-this-case)

The two tables I have are as follows:

```
      Table 1
id  id2    date
1    2   2015-01-10
2    5   2015-06-13
3    9   2015-09-05
4    10  2015-02-11
5    26  2015-01-10
6    65  2015-01-25

      Table 2
id  id2    data(varchar2)
1    2       A
2    5       A
3    9       A
4    10      B
5    26      B
6    65      B
```

The data in `Table 2` is of type varchar2 and contains `N` numbers in it separated by `,` where `N` could be dependent on `id2`. For example, `A` might be something like this:

```
1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9, ...(ommitted)..., 9.5,9.9
```

I want to write a query that returns the unique `data` in `Table 2` that has the maximum date in `Table 1`, which would be the following for the above table:

```
id2    date         number
2   2015-01-10        1.0
2   2015-01-10        1.1
2   2015-01-10        1.2
2   2015-01-10        1.3
      ...
2   2015-01-10        9.5
2   2015-01-10        9.9
10  2015-02-11        ***
10  2015-02-11        ***
      ...
10  2015-02-11        ***
```

Each unique `id2` appears `N` times in the query output.

I am able to get the unique `id2`s based on Fuzzy's answer as follows:

```
select * from (
    select 
        t2.id2, t1.date, t2.data, 
        row_number() over (partition by t2.data order by t1.date desc) rn
    from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t1.id2 = t2.id2
) t where rn = 1;
```

But I don't know how to continue from there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is 80 a fixed value or can it change from row to row?

Comment: @Aleksej I have updated the question description to make it clearer.

Comment: The problem is this horrible table design. It would be okay, as long as `data` would just contain some string for you. But this is not the case; you are interested in substrings stored in `data`. But if you are interested in the separate data, then store it separately! Don't write a query to muddle through this mess; change your database.

Comment: I second @ThorstenKettner. Your data column violates the [atomicity principle] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity) of database normalization. Rather than write a clever query, your solution really should be to extract all individual values from your `data` column and store them as separate rows in a different table.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, and DanK Even though I am far from familiar with database design, I agree with both of you. But I am not responsible for designing the tables. Actually, I am not even in the position to request them to make any change to the current design. I was given this task and am struggling to get it done :-( Thank you both again.

Comment: Then the people responsible for this design should easily come up with a solution. Maybe they can at least write a view mimicking a normalized database.

Comment: The most simple (but slow) solution would be to write a pipeline function in PL/SQL reading the table and producing normalized records. Otherwise you'd probably have to write a recursive query tokenizing the strings.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thank you again for your comments. I am not familiar with pipeline functions, so would it possible for you to share a sample with me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pipeline function:

```
CREATE or replace TYPE test_type AS TABLE OF varchar2(40)

CREATE or replace FUNCTION test_func (d VARCHAR2)
   RETURN test_type
   PIPELINED
IS
BEGIN
   FOR C1 IN (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (d, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) x
                    FROM DUAL
              CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (d, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
   LOOP
      PIPE ROW (c1.x);
   END LOOP;
END;
/

WITH test
     AS ( your_query_here )
SELECT x.id2, x.mydate, y.*
  FROM test x, TABLE (test_func (x.d)) y
```

I am using here mydate instead of date (reserved word) and d instead of data. Sample:

```
WITH test
     AS (SELECT 2 AS id2, SYSDATE AS mydate, '1.0,1.1,1.2,11,1.4,1.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,44,55' AS d FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3 AS id2, SYSDATE + 1 AS mydate, '19.5,19.9,11.5,11.1,21.2,33,1.4,1.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9' AS d
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4 AS id2, SYSDATE + 1 AS mydate, '9.5,9.9,1.5,1.1,1.2,66,1.4,1.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9' AS d
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT x.id2, x.mydate, y.*
  FROM test x, TABLE (test_func (x.d)) y
```

Some links:

[How to split comma separated string and pass to IN clause of select statement](https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement)

[Using Pipelined and Parallel Table Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/pipe_paral_tbl.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have said, if the table was designed properly you would not have to do this.  If this is an object that is going to be used frequently it's better to fix the real issue.  However, if this is just a one-off thing you can use a recursive query.  This works in Teradata, Oracle probably has a similar analog.

```
WITH RECURSIVE processDelimited(ID2,dataVarchar2,parsedElement,indexElement) AS (
    SELECT 
     ID2
    ,dataVarchar2
    ,strtok(dataVarchar2,',',1)
    ,0
    FROM tableWithDelimitedColumns
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
     ID2
    ,dataVarchar2
    ,strtok(dataVarchar2,',',indexElement + 1)    
    ,indexElement + 1
    FROM processDelimited
    WHERE indexElement < 120
    )

SELECT 
 processDelimited.ID2
,parsedElement
,indexElement
FROM processDelimited
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
     ID2
    ,DATE_COL
    FROM table1
    QUALIFY row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY ID2 ORDER BY DATE_COL DESC) = 1) AS id2MaxDate
    ON processDelimited.ID2 = id2MaxDate.ID2
WHERE parsedElement IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY processDelimited.ID2
```

Basically you just start with the empty string and loop through appending rows.

The TD function used just extracts indexes from a delimited field.  Ex.

```
strtok('1,2,3,4,5',',',2) = 2
```

Of course, this is very computationally expensive so it's not really good for a large table.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE VARCHAR2_TABLE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN VARCHAR2_TABLE DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       VARCHAR2_TABLE := VARCHAR2_TABLE();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE Table1 ( id, id2, "date" ) AS
SELECT 1,    2,   DATE '2015-01-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    5,   DATE '2015-06-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,    9,   DATE '2015-09-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,    10,  DATE '2015-02-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,    26,  DATE '2015-01-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,    65,  DATE '2015-01-25' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table2 ( id, id2, data ) AS
SELECT 1,    2,       '1.0,1.1,1.2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    5,       '1.0,1.1,1.2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,    9,       '1.0,1.1,1.2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,    10,      '3.2,3.3,4.5,6.7' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,    26,      '3.2,3.3,4.5,6.7' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,    65,      '3.2,3.3,4.5,6.7' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.id2,
       t."date",
       d.column_value AS data
FROM   (
  SELECT MAX( t1.id  ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY t1."date" ) AS id,
         MAX( t1.id2 ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY t1."date" ) AS id2,
         MAX( t1."date" ) AS "date",
         t2.data
  FROM   Table1 t1
         INNER JOIN
         Table2 t2
         ON ( t1.id = t2.id AND t1.id2 = t2.id2 )
  GROUP BY t2.data
) t,
TABLE( SPLIT_STRING( t.data, ',' ) ) d;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID        ID2 date                DATA
---------- ---------- ------------------- ----
         3          9 2015-09-05 00:00:00 1.0  
         3          9 2015-09-05 00:00:00 1.1  
         3          9 2015-09-05 00:00:00 1.2  
         4         10 2015-02-11 00:00:00 3.2  
         4         10 2015-02-11 00:00:00 3.3  
         4         10 2015-02-11 00:00:00 4.5  
         4         10 2015-02-11 00:00:00 6.7
```